# Need Help for build query with activedataprovider

Tags: mysql, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to perform following WHERE condition in yii2 ActiveDataProvider

Expected Where Condition :

```
$query="WHERE VoterName Like '%s%' AND (contactno != '' OR whatsapp_no!= '')";
```

My current where Condition:

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'VoterName', $this->VoterName]);
$query->orWhere(['<>', 'contactno', ''])->orWhere(['<>', 'whatsapp_no', '']);
```

I want to fetch only those records who have contactno or whatsapp_no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to set multi condition, you must use [andWhere](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-query#andWhere()-detail), for example for your question:

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'VoterName', $this->VoterName]);
$query->andWhere(['OR',['<>', 'contactno', ''],['<>', 'whatsapp_no', '']]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference: `\yii\db\QueryInterface::where()`

Can the following query meet your needs?

```
$query->andWhere(['like', 'VoterName', $this->VoterName])
      ->andWhere(['or',
                 ['!=', 'contactno', ''],
                 ['!=', 'whatsapp_no', '']
        ]);
```

Comment: you were missing a `]` in the end, that would raise a syntax error, just fixed it.